# HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error

Tags: iis-7, umbraco

I am getting the error "HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error" on my umbraco login page.

It was working fine few minutes back I just added the local IP address in IP Address and Domain Restrictions on umbraco folder and later on deleted it as well but now it only works when i change the appool from Integerated to classic

I already have validateIntegratedModeConfiguration set to false in my web.config

any other suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was problem in applicationHost.config file located at C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config.
The default website was also pointing to my umbraco website but in IIS it was not showing.

Restored the old version of applicationHost.config solved the problem